# Calculate the average TimeSpan between a collection of DateTimes

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

Let's say we're tracking the times when a user is performing a certain action, and we want to know the average time between said actions.

For example, if the user performed this action at these times:

- today, 1 PM
- today, 3 PM
- today, 6 PM

The result would be 2.5 hours.

I actually have solved this already, but I felt my solution was more complicated than necessary. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are basically looking for Max - Min divided by Count.

```
    public TimeSpan? Average
    {
        get
        {
            var diff = _dateTimes.Max().Subtract(_dateTimes.Min());
            var avgTs = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(diff.TotalMilliseconds / (_dateTimes.Count() - 1));
            return avgTs;
        }
    }
```

Make sure you check that there is more than one DateTime.

**Update:** Even more accurate if you use Ticks.

```
TimeSpan.FromTicks(diff.Ticks / (_dateTimes.Count() - 1));
```

Comment: You mean, the first DateTime - the latest DateTime, divided by: the number of DateTimes in the collection, or the number of TimeSpans between each DateTime in the collection (so Count - 1)? I assume it's the latter, but I just want to make sure. :)

Comment: Note that if the collection has 1 element you will get a div by 0 exception.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar task in where I had a long running operation iterating over thousands of rows with 20-30 iterations within each.

```
 void LongRunningOperation()
    {
        int r = 5000;
        int sR = 20;
        List<TimeSpan> timeSpanList = new List<TimeSpan>();
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {

            DateTime n = DateTime.Now; // Gets start time of this iteration.
            for (int x = 0; x < sR; x++)
            {
                 // DOING WORK HERE       
            }
            timeSpanList.Add(DateTime.Now - n); // Gets the length of time of iteration and adds it to list.
            double avg = timeSpanList.Select(x => x.TotalSeconds).Average(); // Use LINQ to get an average of the TimeSpan durations.
            TimeSpan timeRemaining = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((r - i) * avg) - DateTime.Now;
            // Calculate time remaining by taking the total number of rows minus the number of rows done multiplied by the average duration.
            UpdateStatusLabel(timeRemaining);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it, but I don't like it much:

```
public class HistoryItem
{
    private IEnumerable<DateTime> _dateTimes;

    public TimeSpan? Average
    {
        get { 
            TimeSpan total = default(TimeSpan);
            DateTime? previous = null;
            int quotient = 0;
            var sortedDates = _dateTimes.OrderBy(x => x);

            foreach (var dateTime in sortedDates)
            {
                if (previous != null)
                {
                    total += dateTime - previous.Value;
                }

                ++quotient;
                previous = dateTime;
            }
            return quotient > 0 ? (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(total.TotalMilliseconds/quotient)) as TimeSpan? : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: something that may speed this up is to put _dateTimes.OrderBy(x => x) above the foreach instead of where it is, perhaps placing it back into _dateTimes or putting it in a temp array if you don't want to modify _dateTimes. Where it is now, it'll reorder the _dateTimes every time it gets a new dateTime for the next iteration of the loop.